# Conditionally include/add a view in xml layout?

Tags: android

Using `Android Studio 4.1`. I have a `main_layout.xml` that looks something like this:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <SomeViewForSpecificBuildType
            android:id="@+id/some_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Other stuff -->
        
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

I want to include `SomeViewForSpecificBuildType` only for a certain build configuration. I.e. for some build types there will be no traces of this view (don't want an extra inflation cost for no reason).

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Is there some `tools:magic` attribute that can be used?

Comment: definitely not `tools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your module, inside the `src` folder , you can create folder for each `buildType` and then create `res/layout` folder and add `main_layout.xml` with different code for different types. When you are running particular build type, it will pick it up from that folder, if it is not mentioned in buildType folder it will use default implementation.

[image]

If you look at above screenshot, `main` folder is where all the code goes, but if you want something to be different , just add the folder inside build types at same path with same name.

Comment: And I suppose this would work for an `<include ...` tag too? So, in my case, there would be an empty layout for some build configurations.